# How can I convert a HH:mm:ss string to a JavaScript Date object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamic string with a `HH:mm:ss` format (e.g. `18:19:02`). How can the string be converted into a JavaScript Date object (in [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8), Chrome, and Firefox)?

I tried the following:

```
   var d = Date.parse("18:19:02");
   document.write(d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds());
```

Comment: [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) - you can't create a date if you only have the time.

Comment: which year, which month, which day??

Comment: if date is unimportant but you want to use functions on the Date object, specify an arbitrary date.

Comment: Did you get your problem soved?

Comment: @Blazemonger As of 2018, you can create a Date object even without a date and time with `new Date()`: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @alex what are you trying to say? `new Date()` has always been valid and takes the clients current date time and time zone as basis. `new Date("18:19:02")` still would be an invalid constructor call under the current spec.

Comment: @Christoph You are correct that `new Date("18:19:02")` is invalid - my comment was that `new Date()` is valid.  This creates a Date object without having to specify an exact date (or time).

Comment: @alex hehe, I got you now. The "as of 2018" confused me a bit, since I though you were suggesting that this is new functionality. Basically you suggest the same I was proposing in my answer? ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (without jQuery and a date object (it's only a time)):

```
var
    pieces = "8:19:02".split(':')
    hour, minute, second;

if(pieces.length === 3) {
    hour = parseInt(pieces[0], 10);
    minute = parseInt(pieces[1], 10);
    second = parseInt(pieces[2], 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how you create the Date object?

Comment: @Yosef its a string parsed solution

Comment: @Yosef See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 24):

You cannot create a Date Object directly just from a time like `HH:mm:ss`.

However - assuming you want the current date(the day portion of the Date object being today) or it doesn't matter for your case - you could do the following:

```js
let d = new Date(); // Creates a Date Object using the clients current time

let [hours, minutes, seconds] = "18:19:02".split(':');

d.setHours(+hours); // Set the hours, using implicit type coercion
d.setMinutes(minutes); // can pass Number or String - doesn't really matter
d.setSeconds(seconds);

// If needed, you could also adjust date and time zone

console.log(d.toString()); //Outputs desired time (+current day/timezone)
```

Now you have a Date object which contains the time you specified plus the current date and timezone of your client.

Answer (score 3):

The Date object is never properly set because of the missing date part. This should work:

```
var d = new Date("1970-01-01 18:19:02");
document.write(d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds());
```