# How to create javascript date object from html input type time?

Tags: javascript, datetime, dom, time

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13802587/5407188) answers how to convert `HH:mm:ss` string into a Javascript date object. The string returned from HTML time input is not always in the `HH:mm:ss` format. The format varies.

The answers in the linked question will not work in-case of dynamic formats.

How to create a Javascript date object from this input value which does not have a fixed format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a HH:mm:ss string to to a Javascript Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802587/how-to-convert-a-hhmmss-string-to-to-a-javascript-date-object) and [Converting time string into Date object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466777) and [Javascript Date Object from string in form 'HH-MM'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332906)

Comment: possible duplicate of [how-to-convert-html5-input-type-date-and-time-to-javascript-datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640351/how-to-convert-html5-input-type-date-and-time-to-javascript-datetime)

Comment: @adiga The answers in the linked question will not work in-case of dynamic formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple answer

```js
function TimeToDate(time) {
    var today = new Date();
    time = new Date('1970-01-01' + ' ' + time + 'Z').getTime();
    var date = today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var DateTime = new Date(date + time);
    return DateTime;
}

console.log(TimeToDate("13:30:7.026"));
```

Answer (score 13):

This is an optimised version of [benihamalu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3797917/benihamalu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56230688/5407188).

```js
const today = new Date();
console.log(new Date(today.toDateString() + ' ' + "13:30"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want current date, in that case you need to get the current date and then pass the current time.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
console.log(new Date(today + " " + "13:30" /*pass your time*/));
```